# Sorting a formula in Mathematica according to level of derivative or exponential

Tags: sorting, wolfram-mathematica, exponent, derivative

I have an impedance equation which I have transferred to Mathematica in hopes to simplify it. It is representative of a circuit schematic, and the circuit impedance (Z, from V = iZ) is a large fraction of several terms in the s-plane.

As an abbreviated example, it could look like:

```
 L0s + (R1/(1 + R1 C1 s) + R3b + L3s + V3/s)/(R2a L2a s/(R2a + L2a s))
```

I would like to rearrange the data as:

```
k1*s^-1 + k2*s^0 + k3*s^1 ...
```

with all values of `k` representing the excess data (fractions of various R-, L-, and C-values).

**What formula manipulation would be best used to craft these types of structures?**
.
.
.
I believe that the `Collect` function is unable to handle separating things out according to exponentials of s, even if the equation is Simplified and then ExpandAll-ed due to the level of divisions between terms - there are several layers of unresolved fractions.

In wondering about this, I was also curious that if I transformed everything to the time domain, is it possible to sort by primes (number of times derivated/integrated)?

```
S c0 + c1 + d/dt*c2 + d^2/dt^2*c3 ...
```

Comment: Your parenthesis are not balanced

Comment: Thanks bel ~ fixed it right away.

Comment: @kando Edited your question to change [ ] for ( ), because square brackets are used in Mma to enclose function arguments

Comment: Thanks again - it's kind of a grey area, between choosing what appears more like actual code and what is easier on the reader's eyes.

Comment: @kando Are you aware of **InverseLaplaceTransform[ ]** to get the time response of the system?

Comment: If all else fails, you can define your own simplification patterns and use `/.` operations to apply them. Hard to tell without seeing the actual Mathematica expression you are trying to simplify

Comment: @belisarius  Yep - my formula becomes so many terms, it is a ridiculous pursuit.

Comment: @Yaroslav I'm with you bud; they don't let me post anything here :/

Comment: @kando you can always edit your question with updates

Comment: @belisarius No, no - I know, I didn't mean it like that, haha - I'm just never allowed to give details about the projects I work on.  The net security here at my company can be a little ridiculous...

Comment: @kando My condolences :D

Answer (score 5):

Your function is not a polynomial in `s` and `s^(-1)`. The closest I could come to making sense of your question, would be to develop your expression into series around `s==0` and then determine series coefficients. This can be done using `SeriesCoefficient`:

```
In[80]:= SeriesCoefficient[
 L0*s + (R1/(1 + R1*C1*s) + R3b + L3s + V3/s)/(R2a*
     L2a*(s/(R2a + L2a*s))), {s, 0, n}]

Out[80]= Piecewise[{
          {(R1*((-C1)*R1)^n*(L2a - C1*R1*R2a))/(L2a*R2a), n > 1}, 
          {L0 + (C1*R1^2*(-L2a + C1*R1*R2a))/(L2a*R2a), n == 1}, 
          {((-C1)*R1^2*R2a + L2a*(L3s + R1 + R3b))/(L2a*R2a), n == 0}, 
          {V3/L2a, n == -2}, 
          {(L3s*R2a + R1*R2a + R2a*R3b + L2a*V3)/(L2a*R2a), n == -1}
         }, 0]
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Or if kando doesn't want the general term, then he can just use 'Simplify[Series[expr, {s,0,n}]]', where the integer `n` is as big as he wants.

Comment: @kando Should L3s be L3*s (in addition to the modification made by Sasha)?  Furthermore, what about R2a? Should this be R2*a (or maybe R*2*a). Similarly for R3b etc. Is the abbreviated equation correct as given?

Answer (score 2):

I could not do anything with your original equation and to illustrate a possible useful approach I will use the following greatly simplified version.  Possibly, this is not what you require at all.

`myeqn = Expand[L0 s + (R3b + L3 s + V3/s)/(R2a L2a s/(R2a + L2a s))`]

giving:

[image]

`Select`, `FreeQ` and `MemberQ` may now be used to define k0, k1 ...  as follows:

```
k0 = Select[myeqn, FreeQ[#, s] &]
```

[image]

Similarly:

```
k1 = Expand[Select[myeqn, MemberQ[#, s] &] 1/s];

km1 = Expand[Select[myeqn, MemberQ[#, 1/s] &] s];

km2 = Expand[Select[myeqn, MemberQ[#, 1/s^2] &] s^2];
```

The following now evaluates to True  (I am assuming that ultimately you require something like this)

```
Expand[k0 + k1 s + km1/s + km2/s^2] == myeqn
```

However, the approach given [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071381/sorting-a-formula-in-mathematica-according-to-level-of-derivative-or-exponential/5072798#5072798) by Sasha seems much better:

```
scoeff = SeriesCoefficient[myeqn, {s, 0, n}];
```

where, for example,

```
k0alt = First@scoeff[[1, 2]]
```